# react-native-image-crop-picker doesn't get recognized by my react-native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

**The problem:**
I've been trying to install and apply the npm package "react-native-image-crop-picker" to my react-native app. I am building the react-native app on windows for android. The problem is that the npm package doesn't get recognized by my react-native app and provides "null".

[Exception on my mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VvVk.jpg)

**What I've already tried:**

- I already checked my android sdk and gradle version and they should be as required
- I re-installed the "npm package" (npm i)and the "react-native-image-crop-picker" (npm i react-native-image-crop-picker)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and this may work for you:
close your metro bundler then:
cd ./android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android